# Is it correct to say "you expect above yourself"?

Tags: idioms, usage

Is it correct to use the idiom "above yourself" in this sentence to mean "having too high an opinion of yourself"? Here's the sentence: "You expect above yourself". What really I mean is, is it correct to use "expect" with the idiom mentioned above? I appreciate for any answer.

Comment: No, you can't just randomly invent variations on idiomatically established forms like this. It's okay to say *He's getting **above himself*** to mean he's ***acting*** in ways that aren't appropriate for someone of his (low) status. Plus it's okay to say *He thinks **too highly** of himself* to mean he ***thinks*** he has higher status than is actually the case. And there's *He has **high expectations***, meaning he expects to be very successful / have high status ***in the future***. But you can't just "mix 'n' match" these usages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Fumble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never heard the expression as a native BE speaker. You might say

> You have great expectations / ambitions.

But you may be thinking of the rather old saying

> You have ideas above your station

Which stems from the time when British society was far more rigidly class orientated and is accusing the person of having ambitions that are beyond the class they were born into.  See also FumbleFingers' comment

Comment: Thanks for your guidance Peter.

Comment: To *have ideas above one's station* and *get above oneself* are idiomatically well-established, but the corresponding versions *to have ideas above oneself* or *get above one's station* don't sound anywhere near as "natural" to me. (Perhaps I just need to get out more! :)